# Углубленное использование модуля CRUD в Play! Framework

Tags: java, crud, playframework

Замечательный модуль CRUD в Play! Framework позволяет генерировать страницы добавления, редактирования, удаления, поиска моделей (классы, расширяющие Model), выводя автоматом String поля и списки как текстовые формы и селекты соответственно. Есть ли какой-то способ использовать этот же модуль, когда в классах Model имеются поля, отличные от String и Collection(List, Set etc.), т.е. грубо говоря Object? Каким образом научить фреймворк внедрить формы и списки и для них на страницу?

Пример моей модели:

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements;

import controllers.CRUD.Hidden;

import play.data.binding.As;
import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.db.jpa.Model;
@Entity
public class Employee extends Model {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<ListOfOrders> orderlists;


    public AndroidDevice device;

    @Required
    public String firstName;
    @Required
    public String lastName;
    @Required
    public String middleName;
}
```

Здесь поле AndroidDevice не показывается на html-View'е данного наследника Model. А оно важно для создания объекта в базе..